# Will apple reject my app - if I don't use split view?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I've developed an `iPhone` app. It's working fine (not published yet). Now I want to develop it's `iPad` version. It has many `UITableView`. But integrating these `UITableViews` in `UISplitView` is complicated, not possible and not logical. So if I develop `iPad` version without `UISplitView`, will Apple reject my app, as I'm not properly using real estate of `iPad`?
In other words, can I use `UITableViews` without using `UISplitView` and will it be acceptable?

Comment: because, I'm not using their recommended design and not taking advantage of large space of iPad.

Comment: This seems like a very pointless question. Why would they reject it? If they did they could reject your app for any reason such as you didn't use `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController` again seems like a very pointless question -1.

Comment: In your own words "recommended design" which means `RECOMMENDED` not `REQUIRED` so you have answer your own question.

Comment: Thank you Popeye for your comments.

Comment: Probably integrating the tableviews inside the split views is complicated and not logical. But this doesn't mean you must necessarily use full screen table views under a navigation controller.you can take benefit on the ipad of container and child view controller concepts to make an innovative UI which is more logical for your app and nice to see on an iPad.

Comment: I don't think it's that pointless. Sure it's easy to answer for people who do have worked on different applications, but not pointless.

Comment: For last 3 days I've been trying to implement splitview controller. But the app doesn't fit in splitview. So I'm thinking of not using splitview. My iPhone contains 4 tabs. Each tab contain 1 to 3 buttons. and clicking on each button takes user to the table view.

Comment: Can anybody give me names of some ipad apps that doesn't use splitview for showing Table View?

Comment: @ThomasJohannesmeyer the reason this is pointless is 1) Apple would never reject your app just because you didn't use a UI object, that would just be silly if they did. 2) This is more of a design question and that is not what this site is for. 3) Because it is a design question it is open to opinion and not facts look under the flagged options you will find **primarily opinion-based** for these three reasons this question is pointless and doesn't belong here.

Comment: I know that. But I think this is not as easy to find out as you may think. If you're new as he seems to be, where would you ask a question like this instead of here?

Comment: @ThomasJohannesmeyer I would probably stick it under the `User Experience` part of the stackoverflow http://ux.stackexchange.com/ as it is design/user experience related unless there was a specific part of stackoverflow that was for design I haven't gone looking so I don't know, but the one place it doesn't belong is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app that I created as a universal app.. I did not use splitview because I wanted the flow to be the exact same for iPhone and iPad and they did accept it.  Is your app just on iPad? Hard to say what they will do in that case.

Comment: Yes. I'm also developing universal app. Thank you for sharing your experience.